# ArgumentOutOfRangeException occured

Tags: c#

I'd make a program which is you can choice your photos from computer to imagelist and listview and then if you click to any photo you can view it inside the picturebox. The problem starting when i open multiple photos in listview first click to first picture there is no problem but when you want to show secondary picture inside to picturebox then I am getting this error :

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException occured
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for
>   'index'.

Can you help me guys?

```
    public partial class TimeLapseForm : Form
    {
        public TimeLapseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int resimSayac = 0;
        List<string> resimKonumu = new List<string>();

        private void TimeLapseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Jpeg Files|*.jpg;|Png Files|*.png;|Bitmap Files|*.bmp";
        }

        private void browseBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string DosyaYolu in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    imagelist1.Images.Add(DosyaYolu, Image.FromFile(DosyaYolu));
                    resimKonumu.Add(DosyaYolu);
                    ListViewItem kucukresim = new ListViewItem();
                    kucukresim.ImageIndex = resimSayac;
                    listView1.Items.Add(kucukresim);
                    resimSayac++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void fullScreenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            TopMost = true;
        }

        private void TimeLapseForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                TopMost = true;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F11)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                TopMost = true;
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to exit program?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.ExitThread();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(resimKonumu[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should protect `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1` handler with unselected indices.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(resimKonumu[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]]);
}
```

Comment: You saved my project :) thank you mate